# How can achieve in bootstrap 3 a layout with a row spanning tow rows and a column spanning two columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, row

I want to achieve something like this
[image]

So, in the image , A is occupying two rows and  B is occupying two columns

I tried, something like this, but as you can see, the logo is never 
two column wide, because it is inside a nested row, so it never[image] looks aligned , it always looks shorter or larger

```css
.row{
    border:1px solid red;
    
}

.row div{
    
    min-height: 100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row upper-row">
        <div class="col-md-7" id="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   x
                </div>
                 
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                   s
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    LOGO
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5" id="">
            A
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bottom-row">
        <div class="col-md-5" id="">
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7" id="">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you mate, on top of this, do you mind if I ask you, how can I make A  have the height of its adjacent two rows ? I think I can do it using javascript, I am just wondering if there is a css/bootstrap easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      A
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      B
    </div>
</div>
```